# Angular ui.router executing more than one state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularUI's router library and I have a strange issue: I have two distinct but similar states and controllers. What occurs is the state that I would expect runs, but then another state appears to run: it fetches the templateUrl and then the controller runs for the second state, which causes some weird behavior.

The states in question:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.route'])
.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
    .state('list', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: STATIC_URL + "js/eleagemot/views/list.html",
        controller: 'questionListCtrl',
    })
    .state('detail', {
        url: '/{username:[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+}/{slug:[a-z0-9\\-]+}/',
        templateUrl: STATIC_URL + "js/eleagemot/views/detailed_question.html",
        controller: 'questionDetailCtrl'
    })
    .state('newQuestion', {
        url: '/new-question/',
        templateUrl: STATIC_URL + "js/eleagemot/views/edit_question.html",
        controller: 'editQuestion'
    })
    .state('questionEdit', {
        url: '/{username:[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+}/{slug:[a-z0-9\\-]+}/edit/',
        templateUrl: STATIC_URL + "js/eleagemot/views/edit_question.html",
        controller: 'editQuestion'
    })
    .state('answerEdit', {
        url: '/answer/{id:[0-9]+}/edit/',
        templateUrl: STATIC_URL + "js/eleagemot/views/edit_answer.html",
        controller: "editAnswer"
    })
});
```

Exactly what happens is if I go to `/answer/1/edit/` it first loads the `edit_answer.html` template and runs the `editAnswer` controller, as it should. But then it also loads the `edit_question.html` template and runs the `editQuestion` controller. I know because there's some Restangular code that runs correctly in the `editAnswer` controller and then some similar Restangular code that runs in the `editQuestion` controller, but that causes a 404 and then the router redirects to the root. Also putting some console logs at the top of each controller shows that the `editAnswer` controller runs and then the `editQuestion` controller.

This behavior is only seen when loading the url for the `answerEdit` state, and not for any of the other states. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should probably post your ```editAnswer``` controller so we can look at that too. It's possible that it could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've got some regular expressions that match too easily. Note that `/answer/{id:[0-9]+}/edit/` always matches the above url pattern: `'{username:[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+}/{slug:[a-z0-9\\-]+}/edit/`

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've added '/question' in front of the ones that are for questions.